# In Angular, how do you set the active route?

Tags: typescript, angular-routing

I wonder whether and how you can set the active route from the script and not just from the html template. To give an example:

```
@Component({
  template: `<input type="button" (click)="back()" value="back" />`
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someService.someObservable$.pipe(first()).subscribe(_ => this.back());
  }

  back(): void {
    // do stuff before navigating back ...
    // navigate to dashboard
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<li *ngFor="let item of commonData">
   <a [routerLink]="item.link" [ngClass]="{'active': item.name === selectItem>{{item.label}}</a>
</li>
```

when you change page or Init take

```
selectItem = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.path;
```

or use the classic routerLinkActive

```
<li *ngFor="let item of commonData">
    <a [routerLink]="item.link" routerLinkActive="active">{{item.label}}</a>
 </li>
```